# Does Duralumin's power vary based on how much of the other metal you have?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn

A Mistborn burning metal and Duralumin gets a burst of power and uses all of the metal he has. Does the size of the burst change based on the amount of the other metal ingested (i.e. would swallowing a lot of steel result in a more powerful Steelpush)?

Comment: I think Word of Author is that it was intended that all of the metal power ingested was released in one burst, which is why when using duralumin Vin usually combined a steel with pewter so the forces involved wouldn't crack her in half.  I'll see if I can find a source later.

Answer (score 3):

According to Brandon (and has @Radhil commented) in [this WoB](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/34/#e5901) duralumin burns your whole reserve in an instant

> **Questioner** What happens if you burn duralumin while Compounding?
>
> **Brandon Sanderson** Duralumin while Compounding. So, what duralumin does is it burns out of all of your metal in one burst. So it doesn't
>   necessarily gain you power, it makes it all happen at the same time.
>   The same thing would happen.

though it may be possible that you run out of duralumin before your other stocks depending on [relative quantity](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/101/#e881):

> **Questioner** I asked the question about chromium vs a Compounder with both
>   invested and un-Invested metals in both their stomach and piercings.
>
> **Brandon Sanderson** What it boils down to is this:
>
> 1) Yes, the piercings will get burned off.
>
> 2) The non-Invested metals go before the Invested ones. He said that
>   because invested metals are harder to [affect], it takes a little
>   extra time and effort to get them to burn off. So a Leecher trying to
>   clean out a Compounder would have to get a good grip and hang on for a
>   few seconds.
>
> 3) Chromium burns about as quickly as duralumin, so if you're trying
>   to burn off a lot of metals, it is possible to run out of chromium
>   before your target is clean. This would probably only be an issue when
>   dealing with larger pieces (like jewelry) rather than your standard
>   metal-flakes-in-the-stomach deal.